# MongoDB query returns topology instead of documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js

I am using MonogDB and NextJS. I am trying to build an endpoint to return all the users. Instead, I get a response of

```
{
"_events": {},
"_eventsCount": 0
}
```

I am using this code to query the database:

```
import { connectToDatabase } from "../../src/util/mongodb";

export default async function buildUser(req, res){
  const { db } = await connectToDatabase();


  const users = await db.collection("users").find();
  res.status(200).json(users)
}
```

And here is the connectToDatabase function:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

let uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI
let dbName = process.env.MONGODB_DB

let cachedClient = null
let cachedDb = null

if (!uri) {
  throw new Error(
    'Please define the MONGODB_URI environment variable inside .env.local'
  )
}

if (!dbName) {
  throw new Error(
    'Please define the MONGODB_DB environment variable inside .env.local'
  )
}

export async function connectToDatabase() {
  if (cachedClient && cachedDb) {
    return { client: cachedClient, db: cachedDb }
  }

  const client = await MongoClient.connect(uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })

  const db = await client.db(dbName)

  cachedClient = client
  cachedDb = db

  return { client, db }
}
```

I am able to get all the users using the mongosh shell and am unsure why I get _events and _eventsCount here.

Comment: Hard to tell what might be happening, but as a bit of debugging advice, wrap your `connectToDatabase` actions in a try/catch.  You may be getting errors that aren't obvious, which the try/catch will, well, catch.  Otherwise you have no validation that a successful connection was established.

Answer (score 1):

`find` returns a `Cursor`, these are just some of it's properties. all you need to do is add the `toArray()` function:

```
const users = await db.collection("users").find({}).toArray();
```

Now this will return the array of documents as expected.

Comment: Using this returns an empty array. As PsiKai suggested, I added a try/catch to my connect to database function. I also confirmed there is a document in there, both through the online dashboard as well as the shell. Any other advice?

Comment: if it's an empty array it means the collection is empty, the most common error i see is when people misspell the collection name for example `users` instead of `user`. the other alternative is that you're connecting to the wrong database. from a syntax perspective this is correct